# Remove reference to csproj Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I received a project and there is a reference that I need to remove, but when I right click on the reference name inside the Solution explorer the option `Remove` is not displayed, when I check the properties, this is the path: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\MyClasses\ClassReferenced.csproj`
This is an image of what I'm describing:

[image]

How can I remove that reference? I'm using ASP.net Core pointing to the `.net` framework.

The reference icon looks like this, it's different from the Nuget icon and from the system icons, it's referencing a csproj file(it's the one with blu color filled besides):
[image]

Comment: Is your project currently running? The 'Remove' option will not be present if the project is currently being debugged / running. What is the reference in question? Is it from NuGet?

Comment: @RionWilliams I'm not debugging, it's the only reference that the Remove options is not being displayed, for every other reference that option is being displayed.. I made an edit in my Q showing the icon displayed besides the reference name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, digging on it I realize that I had a reference to that class library inside my project.json file:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassReferenced": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

So I removed the `dependencies` section and it removed the reference..

Answer (score 3):

For project references in asp.net core, you need to modify your project's `.xproj` file to remove a project reference-- this is an xml file similar to `.csproj`  files.  There should be something like this in there:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\MyClasses\ClassReferenced.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Just remove that section from your `xproj` file to remove the project reference.

Comment: I tried that solution but I'm not sure why it continues displaying the reference, it's referencing a class library that no longer exists, what I'm going to do is go to a previous commit using git when I had that class library available and using the Add Reference option in the Solution tab unchecked that reference, it's the only way I think now, your way should work but I'm not sure why doesn't work on my case, I'll try the way I explained now, thanks